# Using Vue.js directives within component template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and trying to create a component that connects to one object within some global-scope data and displays differently based on the specifics of each object. I think  I'm misunderstanding how the directives `v-if` and `v-on` work within component templates. (Apologies if this should actually be two different questions, but my guess is that the root of my misunderstanding is the same for both issues).

Below is a minimal working example. My goal is to have each `member` entry only display the `Disable` button if the associated member is `active`, and enable changing their status via the button. (I also want to keep the `members` data at the global scope, since in the actual tool there will be additional logic happening outside of the app itself).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <member-display 
            v-for="member in members"
            v-bind:member="member"
            ></member-display>
        </div>
        
     <script>
         var members = [
             {name: "Alex", status: "On"},
             {name: "Bo", status: "On"},
             {name: "Charley", status: "Off"}
         ]

        Vue.component('member-display', {
            props: ['member'],
            computed: {
                active: function() { 
                    // Placeholder for something more complicated
                    return this.member.status == "On";}
            },
            methods: {
                changeStatus: function() {
                    this.member.status = 'Off';
                }
            },
           // WHERE MY BEST-GUESS FOR THE ISSUE IS: 
            template: `
                <div>
                {{member.name}} ({{member.status}})
                <button v-if:active v-on:changeStatus>Disable</button>
                </div>
            `
        });

        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                members: members
            }
        })

     </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `v-if` and the `v-on` for the button just have the wrong syntax.  The line should look like this:

```
<button v-if="active" v-on:click=changeStatus>Disable</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I was sure the answer was more complicated so I missed the basic syntax mistake.